# Is annihilator of principal ideal comparable?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is annihilator of  principal ideal comparable or intersection is zero?

It seems to me there is no reason to believe this is true. But I couldn't found a counter example yet.

Is it true under some conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(12,2x)$.  Then $(2)$ is a principal ideal with annihilator $(6,x)$.  We have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
2&\not\in& (6,x),\\
x&\not\in& (2),\\
(2)\cap(6,x)=(6)&\neq& (0).
\end{eqnarray*}

---

Edit, a simpler example:

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $(4)$ is a principal ideal with annihilator $(6)$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
4&\not\in& (6),\\
6&\not\in& (4),\\
(4)\cap(6)=(12)&\neq& (0).
\end{eqnarray*}